# Use PHP readfile to hide a streams URL

Tags: php, javascript

I need to hide the url of an audio stream and so I have thought that since I have a download script that uses `readfile();` to do this I could do the same but I am not sure how to manipulate this in javascritpt. In fact I have no idea and am not even sure if it is even possible to do it this way.

So far I have a PHP file that is accessed by javascript to get the URL of a track from an ID when the play button is clicked.

```
$T_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['t_id']);
$qry = "SELECT url FROM tracks WHERE T_ID = $T_ID";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$url = $row['url'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($url); //get path info
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename']; //only include mp3 track just incase path added in there
$file_path  = 'uploads/' . $file_name; //add path
echo $file_path;
```

The url from that is just used by javascript to specify the `new Audio();`. However, anyone that know show to open up the console and view the network tab can just find the URL for the track and download it. Which is not what I want or my users want at all.

My preliminary idea is to replace `echo($file_path)` with `readfile($file_path)` but I know that it will somehow need to be manipulated in javascript. If PHP reads the file as binary then can javascript do so too to stream it?

Comment: What needs to be manipulated by JavaScript?  That makes no sense.

Comment: Not related to the question: your code has a SQL injection issue. Consider sanitizing `$T_ID`, by doing something like `$T_ID = intval($T_ID)` (if it is a small integer) or change SQL query to `"SELECT ... WHERE T_ID = \"$T_ID\""`.

Comment: @JiminP: He's already using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize that value..

Comment: @Nick: Something like `?t_id=42 UNION SELECT password FROM user`

Comment: @JiminP: Ah, right, because his value isn't in quotes.. good catch. I stick to PDO, so I missed that nuance :-).

Answer (score 0):

By using readfile(), all you are doing is making the php script into the URL for the download.  The javascript Audio() object still fetches that URL (and maybe start playing before it's all loaded) just as it would with a direct url to the file.  It's not streaming it.  You are just hiding the url to the file.

If you want to offer restricted access, then this is a fine way of doing it, but if anyone can still download using this new URL, then you aren't protecting anything except the actual location of the file.

Also, remember to set headers for the correct mime type, e.g.

```
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_path));
readfile($file_path);
```

You may also want to set cache expiry headers, etc.